# "The driver has not received any packets from the server" JMeter JDBC Request Error

Tags: jmeter

I am going to check my mysql database using JMeter JDBC configuration. I got this error. Is there any way to solve this. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about mysql port 8080 ? default port for mysql is "3306". and if the port is correct you may need to have mysql-connector "mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar" (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ ) in ~jmeter/lib folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I changed my port to 8080 because 3306 not working for me. I added mysql-connector to my lib folder.

Comment: Yugal, I just change my port number to 3306 in Database URL Jmeter. Now the problem is solved. Thank you.